# List of object in list of object

Tags: c#

How can I add a list of object to list of object?

for example:

`new List<ObiektDecyzja>(obiekt, decyzja)` is showing me below error message

> "does not contain a constructor with 2 args"

```
class LiczbaDeskryptorowIlosc
{
    public LiczbaDeskryptorowIlosc(int deskryptor, int atrybut, int ilosc,int obiekt, int decyzja)
    {
        this.Deskryptor = deskryptor;
        this.Atrybut = atrybut;
        this.Ilosc = ilosc;
        this.ObiektIDecyzja = new List<ObiektDecyzja>(obiekt, decyzja);
    }
    public int Deskryptor { get; set; }
    public List<ObiektDecyzja> ObiektIDecyzja { get; set; }
    public int Atrybut { get; set; }
    public int Ilosc { get; set; }

}

class ObiektDecyzja
{
    public ObiektDecyzja(int obiekt, int decyzja)
    {
        Obiekt = obiekt;
        Decyzja = decyzja;
    }

    public int Obiekt { get; set; }
    public int Decyzja { get; set; }
}
```

And then when I'am trying to add to my list

```
List[index].ObiektIDecyzja.Add( new ObiektDecyzja(obiekt.Obiekt, obiekt.Decyzja));
```

Comment: You can double click on the compile error message in visual studio and it should take you right to the offending line of code, alternatively a line number is displayed next to the error. Please include this information when posting on stack overflow. In this case VS would have pointed you directly to the line where the error occurred.

Comment: -4 for asking question that is not metioned at all xD gj guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must first instantiate the list and then yes, add new objects in it,
examples:

```
this.ObiektIDecyzja = new List<ObiektDecyzja>() { new ObiektDecyzja(obiekt, decyzja) };
```

OR

```
this.ObiektIDecyzja = new List<ObiektDecyzja>();
this.ObiektIDecyzja.Add(new ObiektDecyzja(obiekt, decyzja));
```